# Junit tests on ControllerMapper class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm "green" with Junit testing and I have some difficultys testing the ControllerMapper.class of my SpringBoot project. The program works fine, it takes and return json data. I tried to approach the tests after looking at the exercises for RestController testing of Dan Vega and Amigocode on their YouTube channels, but without success.

This is the class I want to test:

```
@Component
@RequestMapping(value = {"","/"}, produces {"application/json","application/xml"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class ControllerMapper {

    //GLOBAL dependency injection
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("rng")
    private Dao<Rng> daoRng;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("user")
    private  Dao<User> daoUser;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fingerprint")
    private  Dao<Fingerprint> daoFingerprint;

    @Autowired
    DataHandlerController dataHandler = new DataHandlerController();

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/finger-identification", produces = { "application/json","application/xml"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object administrationPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ParseException {
        return dataHandler.fingerIdentification(request, response, daoUser, daoFingerprint, daoRng);
    }
}
```

This is the test I tried to build:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(ControllerMapper.class)
public class ControllerMapperIntTest {

   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mvc;

   @MockBean
   private ControllerMapper controllerMapper;

   @Test
   public void administrationPage() throws Exception {
      //given

      //when
      RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/finger-identification");
      MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();

      //then
      assertEquals("true", result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
   }
}
```

Comment: For starters, [`@MockBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) should be used to add mocks required by your class under test to the context. So `controllerMapper` should not be a mock as it's what you want to test. Actually it does not even have to be there as it "_will be invoked via `mvc.perform(...)`_". Howerver, you probably need to define and provide mock behaviours for the DAOs and the data handler it interacts with. See the `WebMockTest` [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) for an example.

Comment: In first place I added  @MockBean private DataHandlerController dataHandlerController, but i replaced it with controllerMapper because this error "Error creating bean with name 'controllerMapper': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'daoRng';" Now I understand that mocks for the DAOs should be added. I will check the article you gave and try to fix the test. Thank you for your advice.